# "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied." on a Ktor request function while using Skrapeit's custom fetcher

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

Source: [Implement your own - skrape{it}](https://docs.skrape.it/docs/http-client/fetchers/implement-your-own)

Getting:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

- HttpClient.request(HttpRequestBuilder = ...) defined in io.ktor.client.request
- HttpClient.request(HttpRequestBuilder.() → Unit) defined in io.ktor.client.request
- HttpClient.request(Url, HttpRequestBuilder.() → Unit = ...) defined in io.ktor.client.request
- HttpClient.request(URL, HttpRequestBuilder.() → Unit = ...) defined in io.ktor.client.request
- HttpClient.request(String, HttpRequestBuilder.() → Unit = ...) defined in io.ktor.client.request

despite it seems to find the first function:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6jFR.png)

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import it.skrape.fetcher.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.android.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.apache.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.utils.EmptyContent.headers
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.http.cio.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import it.skrape.fetcher.Cookie
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class KtorBlockingFetcher(val ktorClient: HttpClient) : BlockingFetcher<HttpRequestBuilder> {

    override fun fetch(request: HttpRequestBuilder): Result =
        runBlocking { // runBlocking because ktor is fully build on coroutines but in our example we want it blocking
            with(ktorClient.request<HttpResponse>(request)) { // do http call with ktor client
                Result( // map ktor result to skrape{it} result
                    responseBody = readText(),
                    responseStatus = Result.Status(status.value, status.description),
                    contentType = contentType()?.toString(),
                    headers = headers.toMap().mapValues { it.value.firstOrNull().orEmpty() },
                    baseUri = request.url.toString(),
                    cookies = listOf(setCookie()) as List<Cookie>
                )
            }
        }

    override val requestBuilder: HttpRequestBuilder
        get() = HttpRequestBuilder()
}

val KTOR_CLIENT = HttpClient(Apache)
val result = skrape(KtorBlockingFetcher(KTOR_CLIENT)) {
    request {
        url { Url("https://google.com") }
    }

    response {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Unable to understand the problem

Comment: What imports do you have in the file? Do you have `import io.ktor.client.request.*`? https://ktor.io/docs/request.html

Comment: @aSemy, yes, I have it.
Edited. Added the imports

Comment: What version of Ktor do you use?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman, I tried multiple versions. Currently, on 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code for Ktor **1.***, but you has included dependencies of Ktor **2.***. Here is the corrected code:

```
fun fetch(request: HttpRequestBuilder): Result = runBlocking { // runBlocking because ktor is fully build on coroutines but in our example we want it blocking
    with(ktorClient.request(request)) { // do http call with ktor client
        Result( // map ktor result to skrape{it} result
            responseBody = bodyAsText(),
            responseStatus = Result.Status(status.value, status.description),
            contentType = contentType()?.toString(),
            headers = headers.toMap().mapValues { it.value.firstOrNull().orEmpty() },
            baseUri = request.url.toString(),
            cookies = listOf(setCookie()) as List<Cookie>
        )
    }
}
```